# Getting a "string" from a "string" in java

Tags: substring

I have a string, "Shirt    base price: $15"

(The string has the spaces in between "Shirt" and "base."

How can I pull out just the "Shirt" phrase of this string?

Comment: `inputStr.toLowerCase().indexOf("shirt") != -1`? ... `Pattern.compile("\\w+").matcher(inputStr).lookingAt()`? ... `inputStr.substring(0, inputStr.indexOf(" "))`? In other words, it depends. Do you need the word "Shirt", or *the first word*? or "the article of clothing anywhere in the string"? How about some more information?

Comment: I have a Jlist with 7 items in it, each being similar to the above. I need the first word from the string. EDIT: There is numerous spaces inbetween the word shirt and base.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split the string at spaces to get the first word in it.

```
String firstWord = str.split("\\s+")[0];
```

The `split` method takes a regular expression to split around, the `\\s+` argument tells it to split the string around sequences of one or more whitespace characters, and the `[0]` gets the first index of the array that was returned.